# why keeps the value of Map<String, dynamic> empty (Flutter application)?

Tags: json, flutter, null

I have a file with the following code and want to use it in another file by import, but the value of Map<String, dynamic> dataList always keeps empty. Why?

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class Structure {
  Map<String, dynamic> dataList = <String, dynamic>{};
  final String apiKey = "Dx6Raz0w6yVEEilPlk2edTmDSJBvTJh7qkou7OwW";
  String query = "Cheddar Cheese";
  String dataType = "SR Legacy";
  String pageSize = "25";
  String pageNumber = "2";
  String sortBy = "publishedDate";
  String sortOrder = "asc";

  Future<void> readData() async {
    query.replaceAll(' ', '%20');
    dataType.replaceAll(' ', '%20');
    String request =
        "https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?query=$query&dataType=$dataType&pageSize=$pageSize&pageNumber=$pageNumber&sortBy=$sortBy&sortOrder=$sortOrder&api_key=$apiKey";

    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(request));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      dataList = data;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to fetch data');
    }
  }
}
```

Then in the other file I tried with:

```
Structure s = Structure();
s.readData();
print('$s.dataList');
```

I also tried with:

```
Structure s = Structure();
setState(() {s.readData();});
print('$s.dataList');
```

but dataList is always empty, why?

Comment: await s.readData()

Comment: doesn't work. I tried to access as follows within statefull widget:             
       ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() async {
                  await s.readData();
                  dataList = s.dataList;
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Load Data'),
            ),

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 mistakes in the code

1. You have to use await -

   await s.readData();
2. You need to use {} in print statement like this-

   print('${s.dataList}');

So your other file code will be -

```
Structure s = Structure();
await s.readData();
print('${s.dataList}');
```

If you want to use it in an widget like an elevated button you can use it like this -

```
ElevatedButton(
  child: const Text('Load Data'),
  onPressed: () async {
    dataList = await s.readData();
    setState(() {});
  },
),
```

Comment: Doesn‘t work. For using await I have to use an asynchronous funktion and I am actually using it in a stateful Widget. See my other comment before.

Comment: Ah I see, I edited the answer and added the code to implement it in a widget. You can't asynchronously setState, that's why you need to first assign the value and then synchronously setState. Hope it helps !

Comment: Will try it out

Comment: Doesn't work, I tried it as follows:   `ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await s.readData();
                dataList = s.dataList;
                setState(() {});
              }`

Comment: Any error or something ? why don't you try the same code that I showed you above for elevated button, 
You should use it like this. dataList=await s.readData();

Comment: readData is of type Future<void>. Please see complete code of class Structure which contains readData in my question.

Comment: no error. The dataList simply keeps empty.

Comment: Can you share the whole code ? 
The code works fine for me